# Global variables in universal React app, Node throws ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm creating a universal React application with Google sign in capabilities.  Unfortunately, Google doesn't have a universal Google API (`gapi`) library that I can use on both client and server.

What I am really trying to do here is run my server code and have Babel recompile my code automatically when I make changes, and have it automatically restart the server (like nodemon does, but with a compilation step).  I found a npm package called `babel-watch` that will do just this, however it doesn't integrate with webpack.

In my template index.html file, I have the following code in the HTML `<head>`:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.gapiPromise = new Promise(resolve => window.gapiLoadedCallback = () => resolve(gapi))
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform:auth2.js?onload=gapiLoadedCallback" async defer></script>
```

The above creates a new `Promise` which is resolved with the value of `gapi` when `platform.js` is loaded.  However, since this is only loaded on the client, `gapi` and `gapiPromise` do not exist on the server.

I also have a Google Sign In React component that uses the global `gapiPromise` variable to do the button rendering when `gapi` is ready to be used:

**GoogleSignIn.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

// should only run on client
if (gapiPromise !== false) {
  gapiPromise.then(gapi => {
    gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: '[removed]'
    })
  })
}

class GoogleSignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // should only run on client
    if (gapiPromise !== false) {
     gapiPromise.then(gapi => gapi.signin2.render('g-signin2', {
        'scope': 'email',
        'width': 160,
        'height': 50,
        'theme': 'light',
        'onsuccess': this.props.onSuccess,
        'onfailure': this.props.onFailure
      }))   
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="google-sign-in">
        <div id="g-signin2"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleSignIn
```

This works fine on the client, but when I try to render it on the server, Node complains that:

```
/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:3568
  if (gapiPromise !== false) {
      ^

ReferenceError: gapiPromise is not defined
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:3568:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:3408:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:3354:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:194:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:59:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:131:31)
```

I have tried prefixing `gapiPromise` in this file with `global.` (i.e. `global.gapiPromise`), and then defining `global.gapiPromise = false` in my server's entry file (`server.js`), but then Node complains:

```
/Users/jreznik/Sites/my-app/dist/server.js:3569
      global.gapiPromise.then(function (gapi) {
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Finally, I was able to get it to work using webpack's `DefinePlugin`:

**webpack.server.config.js**

```
...

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'window': {},
    'gapiPromise': false
  })
]

...
```

But if I do this then I can't use the `babel-watch` npm package to automatically recompile and restart the server.

How can I get Node to stop complaining about these undefined global variables?

Answer (score 0):

It is a **client library**, which means that it is for use only with the DOM from the browser. It is actually equivalent to `window.gapiPromise`. And the `window` object represents an open window in a **browser**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I do understand that, however I am not looking to execute any code from `gapi` on the server, but just render the component server-side (which should only render `<div className="google-sign-in">
        <div id="g-signin2"></div>
      </div>`), and the client will then use `gapi` to render the full button.

Comment: You **can't** use it for server-side because it is a **client library**.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after messing around with this for hours, I found a solution an hour after posting this question.

From my **GoogleSignIn.jsx** file, I moved the code out...

```
// should only run on client
if (gapiPromise !== false) {
  gapiPromise.then(gapi => {
    gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: '[removed]'
    })
  })
}
```

... and into the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.gapiPromise = new Promise(resolve => window.gapiLoadedCallback = () => {
        gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '[removed]'
        })
        resolve(gapi)
    })
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform:auth2.js?onload=gapiLoadedCallback" async defer></script>
```

Not totally sure why Node doesn't complain about the extra `gapiPromise`s in the `componentDidMount()` method, but it's not.  Also I changed the if-statement to check `gapiPromise` to:

`if (typeof gapiPromise !== 'undefined') {`